# adding an integer to the output of a function

Tags: python

I am trying to build a function that generates a random number each time it is called and at it to a constant integer, my function looks like:

```
def offsetradf():
    global x
    x =  random.randint(0,7)
    return x
y = offsetradf()
```

and when it is called later in the code:

```
elif string.find(line,'nslice')==1:
       nslice = nslice+y
       output_file.write(' nslice = '+str(nslice)+'\n')
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./rungenesis.py", line 23, in <module>
nslice = nslice+offsetradf
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do - `y = offsetradf` instead of `y = offsetradf()`?

Comment: `nslice += random.randint(0,7)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Read the error :)

```
nslice = nslice+offsetradf
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```

`nslice` is an `int`. `offsetradf` is a function -- you're not invoking it, you're just naming it. That's all there is to it.

Correct idiom:

```
nslice = nslice + offsetradf()
```

Notice the `()`.

Comment: Actually he did `nslice = nslice+y`, and `y` is assigned the value of `offsetradf()`, as in his code. Don't know about rest of the code.

Comment: The interpreter does not replace your names when reporting errors. I think the piece of code he quoted is not the source of the exception